# moderncv: insert a university logo at the top-left of the page

Tags: floats, moderncv, logos

I'm using the `cvtheme` document class and `\moderncv{classic}` to create a CV. The command `\photo` will put a photograph at the top-right of the page. At the same time, I want to insert a logo of my university at the top-left. That is, at the top of the page, the left is the logo, the center is my name, and the right is my photograpth.

How can I modify the template to achive this? Thank you.

In the example below, I want:

1 My photo is on the upper-right ofthe page, I want to add a logo of my university on the upper-left, above "Apply for a job".

2 I want an icon to show in the front of my address, like phone and email.

3 How to change the orders of address, phone and email? I want the adress to show in the last line.

Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[black]{classic} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[top=0.2in, bottom=0.2in, lmargin=0.3in, right=0.3in]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm} 
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}     
\firstname{\Huge \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad John}
\familyname{\Huge David}
\title{\normalsize{Apply for a job}}
\address{123 Abc Ave. Bethlehem, PA 18015}
\mobile{484--0000--0000}        
\email{abc@123.com} 
\extrainfo{\color{black}Male, Oct. 1991} 
\photo[64pt]{myPhoto.jpg}
\nopagenumbers{}    

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Education}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick workaround could be the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[black]{classic} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[top=0.2in, bottom=0.2in, lmargin=0.3in, right=0.3in]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm} 
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}     
\firstname{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}\Huge \qquad\qquad John}
\familyname{\Huge David}
\title{\normalsize{Apply for a job}}
\address{123 Abc Ave. Bethlehem, PA 18015}
\mobile{484--0000--0000}        
\email{abc@123.com} 
\extrainfo{\color{black}Male, Oct. 1991} 
\photo[64pt]{example-image-a.jpg}
\nopagenumbers{}    

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Education}
\end{document}
```

You can see that I only added command `\includegraphics` to command `\firstname`.

```
\firstname{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}\Huge \qquad\qquad John}
```

I used the example images from package `MWE` (you do not need to call it, but you have to install it on your computer).

Are you sure you want the logo of a university on the top of your cv?  It is your cv, not one of the university or institut you work ...

Result of MWE:

[image: Result of MWE]

Comment: That is very smart. Thank you. It works in my env. I appreciate that.